# Class constructors not initializing values correctly

Tags: java, constructor

I have a main java file and an employee class. For the employee class I have 3 methods - a `getName` method which returns an `employee name`, a `getSalary` method which returns a `salary`, and a `raiseSalary` which raises the `salary` by a certain percent.

In my `Main.java` file, I made a constructor to initialize the values of the employee class, and when I attempt to printout these values, I get null and 0

```
/**
 * This class tests the Employee object.
 * 
 */
public class Main {
    /**
     * Create an employee and test that the proper name has been created. Test
     * the initial salary amount and then give the employee a raise. Then check
     * to make sure the salary matches the raised salary.
     * 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee harry = new Employee("Hi", 1000.00);
        System.out.println("Employee name:" + harry.getName());
        System.out.println("Salaray: "+ harry.getSalary());

        harry.raiseSalary(10); // Harry gets a 10% raise.
    }
}

/*** This class implements an employee which is a person with a name and a      salary.
* 
*/
public class Employee {

    private String employeeName;
    private double currentSalary;

    public Employee(String employeeName, double currentSalary) {

    }

    // Accessors that are obvious and have no side effects don't have to have
    // any documentation unless you are creating a library to be used by other
    // people.
    public String getName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return currentSalary;
    }

    /**
     * Raise the salary by the amount specified by the explicit argument.
     * 
     */
    public void raiseSalary(double byPercent) {
        currentSalary = getSalary() * byPercent;
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, post your code here, not in an external resource.

Comment: For two, your constructor is empty, why do you think your variables would be initialized to anything other than `null` and `0`?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in your constructor do not point to the same objects created outsides it's scope... to fix simply

```
public Employee(String employeeName, double currentSalary) {
this.employeeName = employeeName;
this.currentSalary = currentSalary;

}
```

Adding a "this" before a variable name simply tell the code to point at the variable outside the scope

Comment: to point at the variable outside the scope - Not true. this is a reference to the current instance of the class.  So this.variableName would reference the class instance variable: variableName.